# IPython.display is not showing array in output cell in Jupyter notebook

Tags: ipython, iris-dataset

I am doing a course at Udemy called "Introduction to Data Science using Python". There is a particular section where the instructor imports "iris data" in the jupyter notebook. When i am writing the exact same code, the iris data is getting downloaded but not being shown in the output cell of the jupyter kernel, rather the download is showing at the left corner of the screen (just like when we download a PDF or Excel).

the code i am writing is the following:

"from IPython.display import HTML
HTML(' ')"

I am attaching screen of my jupyter notebook (where the output cell is blank but you will see the iris data at bottom left corner) and the screen of Udemy instructor (where, with the same code, iris data is displayed in output cell) herewith.
would apprecciate if someone could help.

[enter image descripti[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0lVn4.png)on here][2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SgKIM.jpg)png

Comment: Please add the code here as well, so its easier for us to try it.

Comment: from IPython.display import HTML
HTML('<iframe src = https://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/machine-learning-databases/iris/iris.data> </frame>')